# Is there no such sin as a wayward daughter? If so, why not?

Tags: halacha, women, children-parenting, capital-punishment

The mitzvot and sins are not equal in their distribution. Some are only applicable to men, some to women, some to Kohanim, to Kings, etc.

In the case of a wayward (or rebellious) son who is described as "a glutton and a drunkard", is only a son capable of committing this sin? Is a daughter who is a glutton and drunkard not deserving of the capital punishment as he is? If so then why? Is she deserving of any form of punishment?

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna ([Sanhedrin 8:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.8.1)) says the the word "son" is used intentionally to exclude a daughter, in this case.

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 69b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=69b&format=text)-70a) says that while it would be reasonable to also punish a wayward daughter, it is a divine decree that it is not so.

Comment: So the answer is that G-d doesn't want a daughter to be punished for these actions and there is no concrete answer as to why that is the case other than it's the divine will?

Comment: @Echad-Ani-Yodeya That is the gist of these sources. I don't claim there aren't others that say other things, but these are pretty important ones in Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA My Rav discussed this on Shabbat. He cited (I have to ask him for his source, b"n, when I see him) that daughters are never wayward or gluttons or drunkards. Girls don't behave this way. That is why the Torah does not mention them.